# Is there a way to give someone AWS EMR/Ec2 machine access without any download rights?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have not given anyone any download rights through S3 but it is still possible to download data through an EMR cluster using scp

Is it possible to give someone the cluster dns but make sure they can use the data in the cluster but not download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EMR nodes by default will assume EC2 instance profile: `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole`  IAM role to access resources on your account including S3. Policies defined in this role will decide on what EMR had access to.

If that role has s3:* , or s3:get* etc,  allowed , on all resources like buckets and objects, then all nodes on EMR can  download objects from all buckets on your account. (Given you do not have any bucket policies). 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/

Yes, given EMR has access to S3 , if you are sharing the Private SSH key (.pem) file of an EMR/Ec2 with a user, they can use SCP to copy data from EMR to their machine.